# Bootstrap 3 - Text alignment around an image while keeping image as responsive

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3, text-align

I have a text around an image - [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/104936).
When `img-thumbnail` style is applied to image, text is displayed to right but, when `img-rounded` or no style is applied, text is displayed at bottom.

Help to display text to right when `img-rounded` or no style is applied, **keeping `img-responsive` style**. As suggested on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img), I tried with `vertical-align`, but it's not working.

Please help with code, for clarity. Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Whoever had down voted, probably didn't see that I had mentioned: **keeping `img-responsive` style**.

Comment: One of the down voter had cancelled after seeing above comment, thanks to you. Others, if you could explain as to what made you down vote, I'll make sure that I correct myself in future, if I find your response valuable. If I do not agree with you, I will not argue but, your response will help me understand your decision. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i hope this solution will help ( maybe not the perfect one ) but i think it will work for you,
to display text to right when `img-rounded` simply override this class attributes by making the value for display to inline-block instead of block.

**code:**
Change `display: block;` to `display: inline-block;` in the class `img-rounded`.

then you can wrap this section ( image + paragraph ) with a div for customizing the appearance of both.

Comment: I accept you answer as it gave me a hint. Actually, `IMG` is an inline element and `img-rounded` does not override `display` style. It's the `img-responsive` which declares `display: block;` which makes sense in responsive devices. I cannot override that for obvious reasons so, I had made `img-rounded` as inline, as you suggested. Thanks again!